# Реализация вывода анонсов записей (новостей) на веб-странице

Tags: mysqli, php

Интересует реализация вывода анонсов на главной странице, например, как на новостных сайтах, блогах. Не могу придумать оптимальное решение. Например, у меня в БД находится куча новостей в html-виде. Каждая из них строго начинается с блока

```
<p> первый абзац... </p>
```

Единственное решение, которое пришло в голову - при выборке извлекать первый абзац из каждой такой записи, который и будет анонсом. Промучился с SELECT SUBSTRING, LOCATE - ничего не получилось. Хотел с помощью регулярок - а там  POSIX-синтаксис. В общем, головная боль.

Кто-нибудь что-нибудь подсказать сможет по этому поводу? Поисковик выдает результаты, которые касаются этой темы только в движках Вордпресс и Джумла. Ничего не нашел по поводу своего вопроса.

Comment: @Deus, обычно извлекается полный текст и обрезается или используется еще одно дополнительное поле для текста анонса.

Comment: покажи текст своего запроса, который вызвал твою головную боль

Comment: @Fike, я так и делал ранее. Но - тексты могут быть слишком большие, следовательно возрастает нагрузка на сервер, а дополнительное поле - это дублирование информации, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: > Но - тексты могут быть слишком большие, следовательно возрастает нагрузка на сервер

сайты вообще имеют тенденцию нагружать сервер и использовать вычислительные мощности

> а дополнительное поле - это дублирование информации, что не есть хорошо.

во-первых для каких-то статей его наверняка потребуется задавать вручную, во-вторых от идеи без дублирования информации вы отказались чуть выше

Comment: @Fike, я ответил на свой вопрос. См. ниже. )) Кстати, вы правы насчет анонсов вручную - это удобно и для пользователей и для поисковых роботов

Comment: @Deus, а ещё нормальный анонс удобно использовать как описание записи в метаинформации. Например для социальных сетей, они любят к внешним ссылкам добавлять превью с картиночкой, заголовком и кратким текстом. Если с заголовком дела обстоят ещё более менее (title у страницы относительно компактен), то адекватно выбрать из html описание и картинку соц.сети зачастую не осиливают. Так-что приходится добавлять на страницу метаинфу, например в формате OpenGraph.

Comment: @MrClon, в каком формате размещается метаинформация на html-странице, чтобы она добавлялась роботами к внешним ссылкам? Посмотрите, http://hotel-lesopoval.hol.es/ если выбрать какую-либо новость и нажать "поделиться", то робот вставит в контекст ссылки не фото из данной новости и не ее кусок содержимого, а фотку из шапки сайта или еще какую-нибудь хрень. Где можно узнать информацию о правильном подгоне html-кода под роботов?

Comment: @Deus, вконтакт и фэйсбук понимают OpenGraph (описание на официальном сайте и вообще в гугле, там всё просто как мычание). У твиттера кажется какой-то свой формат. Поскольку ВК и ФБ очень популярны, многие сайты размещают у себя OG разметку, и поэтому многие мелкие сайты которым нужная метаинфа опираются на OG. Но других форматов тоже хватает и на них тоже кто-то опирается. В общем единого стандарта нет, но OG кажется наиболее распространён.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предусмотреть в базе специальное поле, куда будет сохраняться анонс, **вручную** введённый пользователем-редактором

или

В статье предусмотреть вставку маркера "анонс", который отделяет основной текст от анонса. После извлечения текста из базы данных на стороне серверного языка (PHP или иное) регуляркой (а куда без них?) фрагмент анонса отрезается от общего текста.

или

После извлечения текста из базы данных на стороне серверного языка (PHP или иное) отрезаются все теги, затем от этого текста отрезается начальный кусок из какого-нибудь количества символов. В запросе SQL тоже может отрезать кусок (`SUBSTRING`) (посмотри ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/322660/ ), и есть [регулярные выражения для отрезания HTML тегов](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Все варианты имеют свои преимущества и недостатки.

*Дополнение*

Обычно тексты HTML хранят в полях типа CLOB (Character Large OBject), в MySQL это поле типа TEXT. Выборка `SELECT SUBSTRING (content, 1, INSTR (content, '</p>') - 1) FROM table` занимает больше ресурсов чем `SELECT accounce FROM table`.

Рекомендации по работе с базами включают такой пункт: избегайте выборки больших полей. Вряд ли для страницы со списком статей требуется полный текст это статьи.

Поэтому заведи поле `announce` размером `VARCHAR(1024)`, затем пробегись скриптом по всей таблице, сгенерируй анонс для каждой строки таблицы из поля `content` и сохрани в поле `announce`. В будущем генерируй анонс на стороне бизнес-логики (PHP, перед сохранением или после изменения записи этой таблицы) или тригерами в базе данных.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, ну естественно! Просто я хочу уменьшить нагрузку на сервер - не вытаскивать весь текст, а только его часть! Например, так:

SELECT SUBSTRING(content,1,1000) FROM table WHERE...

Однако, такая инструкция тупо возвратит кусок текста. Как бы так сделать, чтобы возвращался именно текст, заключенный в первый тег <p>?

В вордпрессе есть фишка - прописывается  в тексте метка <--more-->, и движок сам обрезает текст до указанной метки.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к первому предложению, про отдельное поле. Анонс не есть первый абзац. На случай лени контент-менеджира можно при добавлении/редактировании записи, если анонс не заполнен, писать в него первый абзац (или текст до ката (<--more-->)).

Сомневаюсь что все эти пляски с отрезанием первого абзаца внутри БД будут дешевле даже отрезания анонса в самом приложении. А уж отдельное поле с заранее подготовленным анонсом точно будет быстрее.

P.S. в wp, ЕМНИП, из базы дёргается полный тект и обрезается по кату в php.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (content, 1, INSTR (content, '</p>') - 1) FROM table WHERE ...
```

Извлекает из всех записей содержимое первого абзаца. )))

Comment: первый <p> остаётся открытым

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, да, точно. Не заметил, тогда 

    SELECT SUBSTRING (content, 1,INSTR (content, '<p>'), INSTR (content, '</p>') - 1) FROM table WHERE ...

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, меня интересовала возможность использования регулярных выражений в запросах. То, что я написал выше - это костыль, малейшее изменение в html-коде контента нарушит результат такого запроса.